# How to create a permanent alias in ubuntu

Tags: alias

Can anybody please help me as to how to create a permaneent alias in the terminal.
When i create an alias in the terminal using the

alias name='function'

it stays till i close the terminal.

I am new to ubuntu.
can you please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a file called `~/.bashrc`. If you put commands there, they will be performed every time you start a new shell. Use it to tune aliases, prompt, whatever.